# Filas dentro de filas y columnas bootstrap

Tags: html, css

tengo una duda.

Es posible colocar filas dentro de una fila en bootstrap? Especificamente para un formulario.

Algo como ofrece flexboxgrid.

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <p>Prueba 1</p>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
  
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <p>Prueba 1</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes leer la siguiente documentación

**3.x Docs:** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-nesting

Aquí un layout de ejemplo:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="big-box">image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6"><div class="mini-box">1</div></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6"><div class="mini-box">2</div></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6"><div class="mini-box">3</div></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6"><div class="mini-box">4</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap Version 4.0**

Documentación de la versión 4.0:

**4.0 Docs:** http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting

Aquí se muestra una versión actualizada, lo cual realiza algo similar a la versión anterior de arriba, te recomiendo leer la documentación necesaria para que puedas aprovechar los beneficios:

```
<div class="container">
```

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col mini-box">1</div>
    <div class="col mini-box">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col mini-box">3</div>
    <div class="col mini-box">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero te ayude esta información. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya reviso